# "Address in use" error while running nodejs in jupyter

Tags: jupyter-lab, ijavascript

When i'm using ijavascript in Jupyter to perform fiebase query, an error regarding address in use pop out.

i tried to restart my machine and shut down all other processes that might use port 8888

```
... \npm\node_modules\ijavascript\node_modules\zeromq\lib\index.js:451
  this._zmq.bindSync(addr);
            ^

Error: Address in use
    at exports.Socket.Socket.bindSync 
...
kernel 6d2aa3bc-854c-42e9-9edf-816b3a1dc878 restarted
```